# Cognos bar chart second axis bars overlapping the first axis bars

Tags: cognos, cognos-10

When using Cognos 10 report studio creating a bar chart results in [Overlapping Bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTxzN.png). How can i seperate them so they look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXpKw.png) (i.e. stacked vertically)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination chart but by default your series will overlap. One workaround is to reduce the size of the bar width of your secondary axis.

I would also be interested to know how to overcome the default overlapping of clustered and stacked combination